# Is there a cross browser way to set a timeout on Third Party (cross domain) Async Dom Injected Scripts?

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

Our Tag Manager went down today causing our site to crawl to a hault.  As the code in the tag manager isn't mission critical (analytics, etc...), is there a way to do something like the following?

```js
var extScript = document.createElement('script');
extScript.type = 'text/javascript';
extScript.src = 'http://third-party.com/scriptfile.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(extScript, s);

window.setTimeout(function () {
    // if script not loaded - "give up"
}, 3000); // 3 secs
```

Comment: Can you just insert the script after a few seconds to give everything else time to load first?

Comment: Yes, of course you can set a timeout and then "give up". But what do you want to do on giving up?

Comment: I think he was looking for a way to abort the script so the browser stops "spinning." Consequently, I'm also looking for a way to do this but haven't come up with much.

Answer (score 1):

If its not mission-critical, you might want to put this script at the end of the body tag, as soon as the document has fully loaded.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var extScript = document.createElement('script');
  extScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  extScript.src = 'http://third-party.com/scriptfile.js';

  document.body.appendChild(extScript);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `async` attribute?

```
<script async type = 'text/javascript' src = 'http://third-party.com/scriptfile.js' ></script>
```

this will not block, however you might run into some issues ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr))