# Refresh content of a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this answer has been repeated, but no one worked for me, I don't know why :(. I have one div tag, which contains a script tag (from a website) and loads a kind of frame. That frame displays a monitor thanks to several variables, like the id (which is the most important). So, I want every 5 seconds, the id changes to display another monitor.

The problem is that in my refresh code I use the method load(), but in Firefox I get this warning "A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored." and in chromium I get this one "Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];        
        var number;
        var i = 0;
        function change(){

            if(i<id.length){
                number = id[i];
                i++;
            }else if(i>=id.length){
                clearInterval();
                number = id[i];
                console.log("start again");
            }                   
            return number;
        }

        function refresh(){
            $('#midStag').load("myUrl" +  ' #midStag');
        }

   setInterval(refresh, 5000);
</script>

<div id="midStag">
<script type="text/javascript">
    //I only put the id because is the more important variable 
    //and the only one that I am changing
    id = cambio();
    /*more variables like width or height*/

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dashboard.monitis.com/sharedModule/shareModule.js"></script>
```

I really need it, please. Any help I would appreciate that. If you don't understand something just tell it me and I'll correct. Thank you.

Comment: If you can provide a little [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). It ll be easier to help you :)

Comment: This discussion may be related to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr

Comment: this might work try     $("#panel").toggle().toggle();

Comment: You can't use the script it contains after page load which likely means none of this will work if you expect whatever widget the script generates to work

Comment: Understand that `document.write` destroys everything in page when called after page load has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `shareModule.js` script has a `document.write` statement at the end. And since you are reloading that script when you use `.load()` you get the error since the document has been closed and the script is being loaded asynchronously.

You could do a few things to fix this:

1. Rewrite the script to not use `document.write`, but that requires access to the server it is stored on
2. Save the script locally and modify it to not use `document.write`. The only con would be you would have to update the script manually whenever `sharedModule.js` is updated on the server.
3. Edit the frame's url replacing the needed information, i.e. replace your new id with the old one. Then set the src with the new url.

   ```
   var src = $("span iframe").prop("src");
   src = src.replace(/publicKey=\d+/,"publicKey="+newKey);
   $("span iframe").prop("src",src);
   ```
4. Replace `document.write` with a function that will insert html in a more friendly manner

   ```
   document.write = function(markup){
       document.currentScript.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',markup);
   };
   ```

Demo replacing `document.write`

```js
monitis_embed_module_width = 100;
monitis_embed_module_height = 100;
monitis_embed_module_id = 300;
document.write = function(markup){
    document.currentScript.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',markup);
};

var div = document.getElementById("test");
setTimeout(function(){
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = "http://dashboard.monitis.com/sharedModule/shareModule.js";
  div.innerHTML = "";
  div.appendChild(s);
},1000);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Simulating load...
</div>
```

Demo replacing `src`

```js
var div = document.getElementById("test");
var frame = null; 
function reloadFrame(){
  frame = frame || div.querySelector("iframe");
  var src = frame.src;
  var id = Date.now();
  frame.src = src.replace(/publicKey=\d+/,"publicKey="+id);
}

setTimeout(reloadFrame,2000);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <script>
    monitis_embed_module_width = 100;
    monitis_embed_module_height = 100;
    monitis_embed_module_id = 300;
  </script>
  <script src="http://dashboard.monitis.com/sharedModule/shareModule.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. Second of all, the first and the second thing that you propose it does not work for me because I do not have access to sharemodule.js. The third one, also, it does not work for me because I don't have an url for every frame. But the fourth one, the one which replace document.write, it works but the problem is that always is the same id, never change. And the one which replace src it does nothing. Besides, if I mix the last two, it does not work. So, the best option is the fourth one, but it does not works ok :(

Comment: You do have url for the frame. You just grab the frame that is created and get the `src` as shown and replace the publicKey value. That is the `monitis_embed_module_id` that you set in your own javascript. As for the fourth option, that wouldn't affect changing the id

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand you. Do you refer to the 3rd option? And with the fourth option, I wanted to mean that, the div is refreshed but does not change the id, so is always the same.