# Dynamically adding JS script tag with few attributes having runtime value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, typescript

In our AngularJS application we want to integrate the third party JS file like this.

```
<script id="myID"
  type="text/javascript"
  data-encoding="jsonb"
  data-model="MyModelName"
  data-object="dfdsfsdfsdftrggregerigherignrtintrgntrgjntrjhintrhirnrgoigtrg"
  src="//plugin.wwwwww.ee/js/myreference.js"></script>
```

But we want to create above Script tag runtime so we can get value for data-model,data-object & data-encoding (By Using Controller or other technique)

When we try to add JS file runtime we are getting error in our refered file.

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

on document.write(-----------);

So what is the exact problem, We are using following code on Index.html for adding that JS reference.

```
  var srcFeedback = document.createElement('script'),
  body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  srcFeedback.src = '//vbvcbcvb.bvbcvb.nl/js/ref.js';
  srcFeedback.id = "_plugin_id";
  srcFeedback.type = 'text/javascript';
  srcFeedback.setAttribute("data-encoding", "rrrrrrr");
  srcFeedback.setAttribute("data-model", "rrrrrrrrrrr");
  srcFeedback.setAttribute("data-object",    "regrgegergergvtrcgxercgtrvghtrgtrhct");
  body.appendChild(srcFeedback);
```

Or is there any alternative way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr

Comment: @daf I already checked that but I cant change that third party JS file. Thank you.

Comment: Whats the problem with the current solution, it works, or not?

Comment: Can you not add a script to the page itself, invoked old-school-like with `<body onload="addExternalScript();">` ?

Comment: @daf It does not work due to Document.write error

Comment: @webdeb we cant do that, that file can change with time.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand the problem, could you explain it more precisely?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Dr9efLYs works -- I've tested myself; this is what I was talking about earlier. If you save that somewhere and load in Chrome, from the dev tools, you'll have full access to jQuery.