# Stop a function, in an external JS file, from executing?

Tags: javascript

I am including an external JS file, which has some code that I need to run after a particular thing happens (after contact form is submitted).

The external file has a function but also calls the function. This isn't much of a pain if it was OK to run that function on page load, but I need to run its function after a form is submitted. My form is submitted via AJAX, so I need to run the external file's function after the form has submitted, only.

How can I do this?

Here's an illustration to help...

MY SITE'S FOOTER:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var a_variable = 12345;
    </script>
    <script src="//domain.com/external.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CONTENTS OF EXTERNAL.JS:

```
function doThis(){
   alert(window.a_variable);
}
doThis();
```

But I only want to run `doThis()` at a time that I want, not on page load.

Can I stop `doThis();` from executing until I explicitly tell it to?

NOTE: I have already tried including `external.js` by creating a script tag (in javascript) and loading it that way, but the function in `external.js` needs to write to my users' browser, to which the users' browser says `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`. After that, I looked into the solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr), but it did not solve the problem. So, I am looking for a way to stop `doThis()` from executing.

Comment: I dont understand, just call it when you need it ?. Not right after the declaration of that said function.

Comment: Can't just copy the `external.js` file to your server and modify it?

Comment: What is the actual content of external.js? Sounds like it has a `document.write()` call in it? Perhaps it's an ad vendor's script? Most of the big ad vendors allow for asynchronous use nowadays. For example [Google Analytics has an async mode](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#how-the-asynchronous-syntax-works). Because there's not way to stop a function in an external file from executing.

Comment: You could use the XMLHttpRequest API to load the script, then manipulate the response text and eventually `eval` it...

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the external.js file? If so you should just remove the `doThis()` line and add a listener to call the function on window load like so:

```
function doThis(){
   alert(window.a_variable);
}
window.onload = doThis;
```

If you cannot edit the JavaScript file you are a bit stuck. You could try to rewrite it and just include it locally, following the above pattern (since you can pull the file I assume you have access to the source and could easily download the file and edit it). I would suggest this course of action.

If you really need it to be pulled from that specific source and cannot edit the file, you can look into something like [require.js](http://www.requirejs.org/). This will allow you to load a JavaScript file  from within other JavaScript code, so you can wait for the document to load before including it. So your html could be:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           var a_variable = 12345;
           window.onload = function() {
              require(["//domain.com/external.js"], function() {
                  console.log("loaded!");
              });
           }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.3/require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```