# update json file content with js callback function

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create line like this one

```
<script src="https://www.xtradown.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=200&start-index=5&callback=peter"></script>
```

using that code

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "https://www.xtradown.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=200&start-index=5&callback=peter";
    $("body").append(s);
```

to be able to change it's content like

> start-index=5

to any value I want at any time.

the rest of the code is :

```
<script>
  function peter(e){
    for(i = 0 ; i &lt; e.feed.entry.length ; i++){
        document.write(e.feed.entry[i].title.$t + "<br/>");
    }
  }
</script>
```

unfortunately, when I executed that code I got this message

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

please help me understanding what is the problem.

Comment: You said `the rest of the code is`. Does that mean that is the code found at the xtradown.com url? Or does that mean you're executing that script sometime later in your webpage?

Comment: no, I mean the last part of the code is

Comment: <script>
  function peter(e){
    for(i = 0 ; i &lt; e.feed.entry.length ; i++){
        document.write(e.feed.entry[i].title.$t + "<br/>");
    }
  }
</script>

Comment: full code 
-----
<script>
  function peter(e){
    for(i = 0 ; i &lt; e.feed.entry.length ; i++){
  document.write(e.feed.entry[i].title.$t + "<br/>");
    }
  }
</script>
<script>
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "https://www.xtradown.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&amp;max-results=200&amp;start-index=5&amp;callback=peter";
 $("body").append(s);
</script>

Comment: From what I understand, the peter function already exists on the page and is the callback function to whatever is in the xtradown.com url (you can see it in the query parameters). @peterhany it seems like a round about way of getting a list of the feed,  have you tried any other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is coming from the code inside the for loop of the peter function. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr) you can't use document.write() once the document has been parsed, which it has in this case. It looks like you are using jQuery, so try using something like

```
$("body").append($("<p>").text(e.feed.entry[i].title.$t));
```

That will manipulate the current DOM and should solve the problem you are seeing.