# Replace html block with javascript block of code, gettingFailed to execute 'write' on 'Document' error

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question:**

I am trying to replace a twitter section on a page with javascript widget for Instagram.

**Code:**

```
$('#homepage-social-twitter').replaceWith("<a href='https://instawidget.net/v/user/pfaffmclaren' id='link-37c895c26e36ff'>@pfaffmclaren</a><"+"script src='https://instawidget.net/js/instawidget.js?u=37c895c26e36ff&width=260px'><"+"/script>");
```

**Error:**

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

**Chrome Error Details :**

> instawidget.js?u=37c895c26e36ff&width=260px&_=1535660742861:12 Failed
>   to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a
>   document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is
>   explicitly opened.

Any Ideas on how to swap in a script to a web page dynamically as described above ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute write on doc: It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr)

Comment: @JosephCho I've already looked at that, and see some critical differences

Comment: Not possible with that script since it seems to use document.write which will overwrite the whole page when used after page is loaded and is why it is being blocked

Comment: Yeah it does ok thanks @charlietfl

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s87caz4y/

 - not possible with regular way, but you may use "hook".