# React - “asynchronously-loaded external script” error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, asynchronous

I unsuccessfully tried solving this issue with the solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

I prefixed my question with React because my app is running on React and I'd like to learn how to implement it this way.

I have a `<script/>` that loads its content accordingly by placing it directly on a mundane HTML page i.e:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/tonkihonks/pen/XoqwaE?editors=1011)

```
<body>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.jackrabbitclass.com/jr3.0/Openings/OpeningsJS?OrgID=534011&Cat1=8-Week%20Sessions&hidecols=Gender,Ages,EndDate,Session,Openings&sort=day"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

However, I'm not able to get the same results inside of a react component i.e:

```
class Frame extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src =
      "https://app.jackrabbitclass.com/jr3.0/Openings/OpeningsJS?OrgID=534011&Cat1=8-Week%20Sessions&hidecols=Gender,Ages,EndDate,Session,Openings&sort=day";
    script.async = true;
    document.querySelector(".frame-container").appendChild(script);
    //document.querySelector(".frame-container").insertBefore(script);
    //document.querySelector(".frame-container").innerHTML = script;
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="frame-container" />;
  }
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Did Frame load?</p>
      <Frame />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get the follwing error:

`Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`

How could I properly load the given `<script />` content inside of a React Component?

Also, here's a code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6v36vj1vx3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute write on doc: It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr)

Comment: Your external script is using the `document.write`API (which is really weird)

Comment: @LucaFabbri would that be on their end (their external script) and is there something I could do to remedy that?

Comment: Have you tried the same without adding `async` attribute to your script tag?

Comment: @NullisTrue is doable for you to just put the JS script in your HTML?

Comment: @ShevchenkoViktor I did. Same error.

Comment: @LucaFabbri please remove the duplicate from my question, as I already referenced the suggested duplicate inside my own question. I applied the solutions suggested on that question but I couldn't get it to work. I can't put the js `script` inside of my index.html because the content is generated on a React Component.

Comment: Sorry, but IMHO this is still a duplicate. Explanation of the issue and answer (do not use `document.write`) are in the linked answer

Comment: I'm not passing/using `document.write`, rather I tried `innerHTML`, `apendChild` and `insertBefore` could you please post an answer here for what you have in mind?