# React useEffect appended script not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to load a script that once triggered generates an iframe and a weather widget. I can get the script properlly appended, but it does not get called and does not generate the iframe

I've tried just adding the script directly in the render, it will load the iframe briefly then switch back to the script tag

```
const City = ({ content, schema }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
  "https://darksky.net/widget/graph-bar/32.7174,-117.1628/us12/en.js?width=100%&height=400&title=Full Forecast&textColor=333333&bgColor=FFFFFF&transparency=false&skyColor=undefined&fontFamily=Default&customFont=&units=us&timeColor=333333&tempColor=ff8200&currentDetailsOption=true";
    script.async = true;

    document.getElementById("widget").appendChild(script);
  }, [])

  return (<div id="widget"></div>);
};

export default City;
```

Comment: Since you are appending to the widget div, why don't you just write the script tag inside the return?

Comment: @Chris I tried that and it triggers, but flashes and goes back to being a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the warning displayed in console:

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

See [Execute write on doc: It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr)