# svelte : embedded github gist throws Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document'

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, gist

I cannot find a way to embed a **github gist** in my local svelte application.

Whatever I do, the client console throws me a
`Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`
error or simply doesn't display anything.

This is maybe evident, but it seems github embedded gists use **document.write** to create the gist element at the script emplacement while the document is loaded

[This issue on svelte repo](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4866)
seems related, but only talks about the demo REPL of the svelte website...

What I tried so far :

- just embed the `script` tag given by github in my page.svelte -> error above
- embed it in the template `index.html` for testing -> this worked but obviously you have the gist at the top of any page...
- create a `Gist.svelte` component with the following code -> error above

```html
<!-- Gist.svelte -->
<script>
  export let gistUrl = ""

  import { onMount } from 'svelte'

  let container;

  onMount(() => {
    const child = document.createElement('script')
    child.src = gistUrl + ".js"
    //child.defer = true
    container.appendChild(child)
  })
</script>

<div bind:this={container}/>
```

```html
<!-- page.svelte -->
<!-- ... -->
  <Gist gistUrl="the_gist_url"/>
<!-- ... -->
```

PS : I did not dare open a new issue about this before asking stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by rendering the Gist in an `<iframe>`:

```html
<!-- Gist.svelte -->
<script>
  export let gistUrl = ""

  import { onMount } from 'svelte'

  let frame;
  onMount(() => {
    frame.srcdoc = `<script src='${gistUrl}.js'><${""}/script>`;
  });
</script>
<style>
  iframe {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<iframe src="about:blank" bind:this={frame} title="Gist"></iframe>
```

[Try it in the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2d4d41df9f404b2d896bb81c55cb75c0?version=3.35.0)

Comment: thanks, this works indeed, but i guess you cannot control the size of an iframe to fit its content (i assume this from earlier attempts, I may be wrong ?), because it creates a scroll bar. I'll look into it

Comment: @gui3 I haven't been able to get it to fit the Gist either. i've been getting cross-origin policy errors trying to detect the inner size.

Comment: I'll wait a bit to see if someone comes with a better workaround (iframe sizing is a minor problem, but a problem indeed) before accepting your answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not svelte specific. An asynchronously loaded script like the embedded github gist is going be run after the document (created by svelte) has been fully parsed and closed. This is why placing the  tag in the index.html works (because document is still open). For more information check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr)

Comment: thank you for the explaination and the link, i stubled upon this SO question before asking but since I cannot change the gist script this did not help. What I am looking for is a **workaround** to include neat github gists into my web page