# Dynamic script not firing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a github gist to my webpage on the click of a button however the gist is not appearing.

```
function createGist(gistId = "bd10e846c6eae4419c3041f3da1b82a0"){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://gist.github.com/snakifyanswers/" + gistId + ".js";
    document.body.appendChild(script)    }
```

I am left with nothing there even though in inspect element I can see the script object.

Comment: Being able to see it in the inspector sort of implies it's there; what do you mean by "not appearing"?

Comment: It is there however when I add `<script src="https://gist.github.com/snakifyanswers/2d526d30bfdaddc3b1853f96456e0947.js"></script>` to my html file it displays the gist I want to show however the scr script is not running when I add the element via javascript.

Comment: It doesn't work because the script uses `document.write`. Have a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr)

Comment: How do you know it isn't running?

Comment: Using postscribe I have got the gist to appear.

Comment: Please self-answer the question with your solution (and perhaps edit the question to include more details). On SO we don't mark titles with tags; we mark an answer as accepted.